# Sketch of the ordinate set of $f$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Let $f$ be defined on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ as follows:

$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} x+y \mbox{ if } x^2 \leq y \leq 2x^2 \\ 0 \mbox{ otherwise} \end{cases}$

I want to make a sketch of the ordinate set of $f$ over $[0,1] \times [0,1]$  and compute the volume of this ordinate set by double integration (Assuming the integral exists)

Comment: "compute the volume" or "compute the area"?

Comment: @AméricoTavares compute the volume (according to my book)
We are talking about volume since we are consider two integrals. In the single variable case, we got the area. In the two variable case, it's a volume.

Comment: I was wrong. Please forget my comment.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol What's the ordinate set of a function?

Comment: @GitGud If f is nonnegative, the set S of points (x,y,z) in 3-space with (x,y) in $[0,1]^2$ and $0 \leq z \leq f(x,y)$ is called the ordinate set of f over [0,1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment by OP:

> If $f$ is nonnegative, the set $S$ of points $(x,y,z)$ in 3-space with
>   $(x,y)$ in $[0,1]^2$ and $0\le z\le f(x,y)$ is called the ordinate set
>   of $f$ over $[0,1]$.

---

My interpretations is as follows. The picture represents a region $R$ bounded by $y=2x^2$, $y=x^2$ (with $0\le x\le 1$) and $y=1$.

[image]

$$y=2x^2\text{ (blue)}, y=x^2\text{ (green)}$$

The volume bounded by $R$ and $0\le z\le x+y$ is given by

\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\iint_{R}x+y\,dA=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2}\left(
\int_{x^{2}}^{2x^{2}}x+y\,dy\right) dx+\int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^{1}\left(
\int_{x^{2}}^{1}x+y\,dy\right) dx \\
&=&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2}x^{3}+\frac{3}{2}x^{4}\,dx+\int_{\sqrt{2}%
/2}^{1}x-x^{3}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x^{4}\,dx \\
&=&\frac{1}{16}+\frac{3}{80}\sqrt{2}+\frac{37}{80}-\frac{19}{80}\sqrt{2} \\
&=&\frac{21}{40}-\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You are welcome! I would like to give credit to @Fly by Night by his idea in his answer deleted in the meantime. If there's any error, the fault is mine.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol Could you tell me how does one translate "ordinate set" into French?